# InteliJ Idea in WSL2 error : export: ProgramFiles(x86): bad variable name

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm getting the error

```
export: ProgramFiles(x86): bad variable name
```

when trying to run a java program on WSL2 from IntelliJ Idea. I can't seem to find any log or lead to this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you get the answer already, please uncheck your "include system environment variables" and save, it should works.
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it makes more sense than disabling the env plugin because windows environment variables are invalid from Linux perspective which I think is what triggers this error export: ProgramFiles(x86): bad variable name

Answer (score 5):

Disabled EnvFile plugin, I resolved this problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30672234)

Comment: This fixed the issue, but I guess it's a bug/conflict which need to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the .env files support and envFile dependencies

Comment: .env files support does nothing with running programs. It's only for .env syntax and some completions.

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't an exact answer, but I ran into the same problem.  I removed a bunch of unused extensions and it solved the issue - sadly I don't know which was the culprit.  So my advice is to disable all of your extensions and slowly enable them back to see which one is breaking it.